# Raspberry pi ssh access is denied

Tags: ssh, debian, raspbian

I have raspberry pi 3 b+ with raspbian os.
Ssh worked perfectly for couple of days.
I used default username and password for ssh connection

After including large mysql database ssh disconected and now, when i try to log in, raspberry display me error message :" Error, access is denied!" Password and username is correct.

What kind of problem it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as root under Linux sudo/su 'ssh -v -p 22 "username"@"raspberry"'? -v = verbose and show you what ssh does. -p = port standard port for ssh was 22.
And you can try it with an other PC/laptop or with a smartphone app like juicessh (Android)